# Python - vtkDICOMImageReader array input?

Tags: python, vtk, dicom, pydicom

I'm building a system for viewing DICOM files. DICOM files located in the specified folder are read with `dcmread` and put in a list. I check the metadata to separate the series by the series number in the information, then I create a dictionary with several lists, one for each series, which contain the respective scans. In the program, therefore, I can select which series to display with the 3D reconstruction. I noticed however that with `vtkDICOMImageReader` I can only specify a file or a directory. Can I also select a list containing DICOM files in some way?

Comment: what does this have to do with pydicom?

Comment: @Richard I use pydicom.dcmread to read files from directories. The resulting array contains the scans read via this function, which I have to somehow view with vtk

Answer (score 0):

`vtkDICOMImageReader` derives from `vtkImageReader2`, you can use the `vtkImageReader2::SetFileNames(vtkStringArray *)`

- https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageReader2.html#ac084edcfab5d27247a7683892a95617e

---

By design vtkImageReader2 needs to read the files from disk (think UpdateExtent != WholeExtent).

If you are looking to import a c-array as an image into VTK, you should instead start using:

- https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageImport.html

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but SetFileNames() takes in an array of strings that contains the names of the files to be read on disk, while I have an array that contains the DICOM files already read from the disk with dcmread